# how to merge same object in json file using python

Tags: python, json, merge, updates

1.json file contain many sniffing WIFI packets, I want get the mac address of receiver and transmitter which can be found in the first "wlan" object called "wlan.ra" and "wlan.sa". data[0] is the first WIFI packet.

Q1:
But when I try to print the elements of wlan after json load, it only show the elements of the second "wlan" object so there is no "wlan.ra" and "wlan.sa" in the data.

```
with open('1.json','r') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
a=data[0]
print  a
```

Q2:
There are two 'wlan' objects in my json file. How can I merge the elements in these two 'wlan' objects into just one 'wlan' object?

The following is my code, but it doesn't work:

```
with open('1.json','r') as f:
     data=json.load(f)  
     for i in data:
         i['_source']['layers']['wlan'].update()
```

Screenshot of json file:

[image: Wlan obj - 1.json]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'''
Created on 2017/10/3

@author: DD
'''

import os

def modify_jsonfile(jsonfile):
'''
replace wlan to wlan1/wlan2
'''
FILESUFFIX = '_new'  # filename suffix
LBRACKET = '{'  # json object delimiter
RBRACKET = '}'
INTERSETED = '"wlan"'  # string to be replaced
nBrackets = 0  # stack to record object status
nextIndex = 1  # next index of wlan
with open(jsonfile, 'r') as fromJsonFile:
    fields = os.path.splitext(jsonfile)  # generate new filename 
    with open(fields[0] + FILESUFFIX + fields[1], 'w') as toJsonFile:
        for line in fromJsonFile.readlines():
            for ch in line:  # record bracket
                if ch == LBRACKET:
                    nBrackets += 1
                elif ch == RBRACKET:
                    nBrackets -= 1
                if nBrackets == 0:
                    nextIndex = 1
            if (nextIndex == 1 or nextIndex == 2) and line.strip().find(INTERSETED) == 0:  # replace string
                line = line.replace(INTERSETED, INTERSETED[:-1] + str(nextIndex) + INTERSETED[-1])
                nextIndex += 1
            toJsonFile.write(line);
print 'done.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
jsonfile = r'C:\Users\DD\Desktop\1.json';
modify_jsonfile(jsonfile)
```